# RC script that brings itself to foreground under certain criteria

Tags: freebsd, rc

I have a simple script that asks for user input ([y/N]) and then acts upon it. I wrote a daemon `rc` wrapper so that it can run from startup. I was wondering if it is possible to make the daemon/script ask for the user input and then background itself until it is time to ask again, at which point it foregrounds itself? Is this possible? Is this practical? Where should the fg/bg control be hosted? in the `rc.d` script or in the main script?

Comment: A system service that needs to prompt a user for input is bad design. You should likely rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I figured that would be at least one answer. Thank you. I'll redesign the script to be completely automated.

Comment: An approach that might come close to what you want is (1) have the background/daemon program provide a minimally-intrusive visual indicator when it wants input — something similar to the "system tray" on Windows, and (2) provide a separate, interactive program, that the user would be able to initiate manually (i.e., that would not start until the user started it) and that would then communicate the user's input to the background process via some sort of IPC.

Comment: @G-Man That would work possibly. Unfortunately I do not use any GUI. This is a remote server which has no X11.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't have to be a GUI mechanism.  It could be writing some characters to the tty (maybe visual/textual, maybe an escape sequence to flash the screen, maybe a string of bell characters), it could be an email, it could writing to a file that your shell's PROMPT_COMMAND checks, etc.  There are lots of ways of implementing it.

Comment: Your daemon needs a client. The service runs and the client interacts. So your service speaks some protocol on some predefined channel, and your client also speaks the protocol and attempts to connect to it when it is called as a command. Best would be a unix socket setup in /var/run or something. Or else, if you buy into all that stuff, dbus.

Comment: @mikeserv I know very little about sockets. What should I research? Do you have any suggests readings?

Comment: Well, with dbus you can set it all up with shell tools. Do `dbus` and then a *tab* at a prompt to get an idea of where to start. I don't envy you the work just trying to grasp dbus fundamentals might entail. More simply you can do it with `netcat` or `socat` where you background a socketized service on some port or on a unix socket file. I'm far from being an expert either, though, but you can start at `man 7 socket`. Also have a look at the `man` pages for `socat` and `netcat`. And be sure to install the BSD `netcat` and *not* the GNU `netcat` it you go with it.

Comment: @LukeSmith: If you just want to throw a rock into your neighbor's yard, you don't need a rocket, and if you don't need a rocket, you don't need to learn rocket science.  Sockets are the greatest thing since sliced bread, but if you're writing scripts, and everything's on the same machine, caveman science suffices: just use files or named pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't block the startup process for the sake of one service, unless it's some absolutely critical service without which the machine is unusable (e.g. entering a passphrase to decrypt the OS disk).

If some service needs manual intervention to start (which should be avoided if at all possible, unless you like getting paged at 3am because the service didn't come back after an unscheduled reboot due to a UPS failure), make sure that it doesn't block the boot. Put whatever needs to be done in the background.

To allow users to interact with the service, run it inside [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (or tmux if you prefer tmux) to create a pseudoterminal where the service will read input from and write output to.

```
screen -d -m -S myservice /usr/local/sbin/myservice --interactive-start
```

To connect to the terminal created by Screen, use

```
screen -r -d -S myservice
```

You can do that from anywhere: on the console, over SSH, etc. You need to run the `screen` command as the same user both times. To detach from the Screen session and leave it running in the background, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.